# timidity : couldn't open output device

Tags: mp3, wav, midi

I have installed timidity on a dedicated Linux server.
when I try to convert a midi to a wav or mp3:

timidity toto.midi -Ow -o out.wav

I always get an error
**couldn't open output device**

Any idea ?

regards

Comment: Not a programming question, ask this on superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

On linux, timidity likes to open `/dev/dsp` even when it doesn't need to (for bystanders, `-Ow` means wav file output).

Virtual servers often don't have a meaningful `/dev/dsp`.  There are several VMs wanting to use the same audio hardware, which in any case lacks speakers and an audience.

On my box, I solved this by symlinking `/dev/dsp` to `/dev/null`:

```
cd /dev
rm dsp        #/dev/dsp was a symlink to /dev/dsp0
ln -s null dsp
```

Which works.  To bed that in over reboots, you need a file called something like `/etc/udev/rules.d/z42_fake_dsp.rules`, with contents a bit like this:

```
KERNEL=="null", SYMLINK+="dsp", OPTIONS+="link_priority=99"
```

though I haven't actually tested it over a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have `timidity` installed, but reading the man page:

- http://linux.die.net/man/1/timidity

It says:

```
timidity [options] filename [...]
```

The options look OK, but try following the order (some programs have ordering issues):

```
timidity -Ow -o out.wav toto.midi
```

The other thing that might be an issue is that you really cannot write to `out.wav` file, so check:

- That there's no out.wav in the current folder,
- That you are in a folder you have write permissions to

Comment: I tried it : same result !
timidity -Ow -o out.wav toto.midi
Couldn't open output device

Answer (score 0):

Similar error happened to me when I build timidity from source.
Configured by:
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-audio=default,alsa,ao

But later I discovered my configuration had:
conftest.c:73:10: fatal error: alsa/asoundlib.h: No such file or directory
73 | #include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

So after
apt install libasound2-dev # as root

## re-configure as above,

./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-audio=default,alsa,ao
make
sudo make install

Now timidity runs fine.